# Finder move does not merge but replaces old folder, how to get old folder's contents

Tags: macos, finder, folders, filesystem

I moved folder named FOLDERA to another folder where same name folder exists. Finder asked me to replace? I complied thinking that it will merge two folders like windows. It completely replaced my older folder.

- Undo (-Z) does not bring back
- Trash does not show my old files

Is there any way to bring back these files?

Comment: I would say you are out of luck :(  http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120218074834885

Comment: You could try using [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/) or [Data Rescue](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php).